# Saving Illustrator logo for common to use formats

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, export

I've got pretty simple problem. I've created logo in 3 variations on 3 A4 format artboards. I want to crop them, to get rid of loads of white space around logo, and secondly i'd like to save it with transparent background. Thanks in advance.

PS. I can't find any resources of best practices when saving logo in different formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select the logo.
- `Object > Artboards > Fit to Selected Art`

As for a transparent background, Illustrator files inherently have no background. You can turn on the Transparency Grid if you need to confirm that -- `View > Show Transparency Grid`. The only reason you would have a background is if you used raster images or raster effects within your logos. You don't need to traditionally do *anything* to an Illustrator file to remove a background.

Answer (score 2):

if it is the whitespace in the *artboards* themselves you want to get rid of, you can either:

- group all the elements in one artboard and go to file - document
  setup - edit artboards and then click (doubleclick?) on the grouped
  logo. That should bring the artboard down to the exact size

or

- you could go file - document setup - edit artboards and then do it
  manually with resize

[image]

To save with transparent background, choose png: file - save as

Make sure you have chosen one of the artboards (this is signified by a slightly thicker black line around it). This should make you able to save one logo at a time, and prevent you from getting one massive image with all three.